# UIScrollview paging issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7

I have a **UIScrollView** with paging enabled, my goal is to detect if the user reaches third page by swiping, I want to redirect the user to another view. I have tried many ways. tried it in ***scrollViewWillBeginDragging*** , tried inbuilt pan gesture in scrollview methods using ***handleSwipeGesture*** . But unfortunately nothing worked. Can any body please tell me how to face this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use this code

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    int page=scrollview.contentoffset.x/scrollview.frame.size.width

    if(page == 3)

    {
    // redirect to your view.
    }

}
```

This will give you the page no. you are currently on. and the condition will redirect to a specified view.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aashna Dhingra, I haven't tried this one. And thats working like charm :)  I've just joined the stack overflow so I don't have much points to up vote :) thanks again. Happy Coding